# Can I add a button onClick handler via Andriod Studio GUI?

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick

In Android Studio (3.5.3), is it possible to add a button onClick handler via the GUI?

When the onClick dropdown (red box) is clicked, there are no options. When I typed in something manually (as in the picture) no code was generated.

I can add a button handler to my activity in the code, which works fine, but nothing is populated in the "Common Attributes" on this screen.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> You have multiple options, but in any one you have to do some effort:

**First:** you can type anything in `onClick` attribute and press Enter then will place below in your layout

```
<Button
    android:onClick="onClick"
```

**Your effort:** you've either to

1. Switch to the Text tab of your layout, press ALT + ENTER on the
   warning on "onClick" attribute, and then choose `Create onClick
   Handler`, choose the activity and hit OK.

[image]

[image]

2. Switch to your activity behavior class and add below method.

   public void onClick(View view){

   }

**Second:** you can reverse the order of the first method, so you can first create your click handler callbacks in your activity, and then choose them for buttons on the design tab, and here you can use the drop-down menu of the onClick().

Here I created a couple of callbacks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    public void onClick2(View view) {

    }

}
```

And then you can choose any from the designer tab onClick attribute

[image]